# Not all post displaying in wordpress filter

Tags: wordpress

I have a page with a filter that shows posts by category.  It successfully filters. 
this is the select code:

```
<select class="selectBox" id="division" name="division">
  <option value="0">Topic</option>
  <option value="Compliance">Compliance</option>
  <option value="Intelligence">Intelligence</option>
  <option value="Investigations">Investigations</option>
</select>
```

If you click on the topic option and click the submit button, it should return all posts again, but it stops at 10 posts.

here is the filter code which is in the functions.php file

```
function ajax_filter_function(){
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'date', // we will sort posts by date
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type'=>'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish'

);

// for categories
if(!empty( $_POST['division'] ) && !empty($_POST['type']) ) {
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'terms' => array(strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$_POST['type'])))
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'terms' => array(strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$_POST['division'])))
        )
    );
}elseif(!empty( $_POST['division'] )) {
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'terms' => array(strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$_POST['division'])))
        )
    );
}elseif(!empty( $_POST['type'] )) {
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'terms' => array(strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$_POST['type'])))
        )
    );
}else{
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'terms' => array('resources')
        )
    );
}
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
        $post_cat = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'primary_category', true);
        echo'<li style="background:url('.get_the_post_thumbnail_url($query->ID,'full').') no-repeat;background-size:cover;background-position:center;">
            <a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">
                <div class="cat-bar '.strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$post_cat)).'">'.ucwords($post_cat).'</div>';
                $post_cat = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'primary_category', true);
                foreach ( (get_the_category() ) as $child ) {
                    if ( $child->cat_name != $post_cat && $child->cat_name != 'Uncategorized' && $child->cat_name != 'Thank You Page'){
                        echo'<div class="cat-bar sec-cat filtered-cat">'.$child->cat_name.'</div>';
                    }
                }
        echo '<div class="title-section"><div class="title">'.get_the_title().'</div>';
        if($post_cat == 'Event') { 
            echo'<div class="date"><img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/img/new/clock.png" /> '.get_field('event_date', get_the_ID()).'</div>';
        }else{ 
            echo'<div class="date"><img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/img/new/clock.png" /> '.get_the_time('F jS, Y').'</div>'; 
        }
        echo'
                </div>      
            </a>
            </li>
        ';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
else :
    echo '<p style="width:100%;text-align:center;">Sorry, no resources match that criteria. <a href="/resources">Remove filters</a> and try again.</p>';
endif;

die();
```

}

add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'ajax_filter_function'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'ajax_filter_function');

And for reference, [this](https://tdinternational.com/resources/) is the site where it exists.
You will notice that if you click filter, it removes the last two posts.

help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't supply a `posts_per_page` parameter in your query it will default to the value set in Settings > Reading, which is typically 10.

Add the `posts_per_page` parameter to your query args with a value of `-1` in order to show all posts, or adjust the value as needed:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'date', // we will sort posts by date
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type'=>'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
```